# Is there a way to check the index something is at in a list?

Tags: python

I am writing code for a hangman game in python and I need to know the index of some of the letters which are in a list.

Here is my code:

```
if answer in word:
    check.append(answer)
    if check[0]==answer:
        print('u guessed one')
        guessed.append(answer)
        check.remove(check[0])
        print('You have guessed',guessed)
```

I know that I have to find the position  of the guessed letter but I don't know how..

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: What variable do you have to find the position of in what array?

Comment: If it is not too taxing for you: google for 'python string index' and hit the first link proposed, read an apply. If you don't want to use the string method described there but walk over the elements yourself, look-up `python enumerate`. And you can of course do `idx =0` and then `idx += 1` in the loop, if you really have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what you want to find the position of (sloppy variable naming) but I think you are trying to find the position of `check[0]` in `word`. To do this you use [index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm), a built in function:

```
position = word.index(check[0])
```

If `word = "cake"`, and `check[0] = a` then, the position would be `1`, since `a` has an index of `1` in `word` (`['c', 'a', 'k', 'e']`).